# Planar graph memory

Tags: graph-theory

I have a [Planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) with `n` nodes and `e` edges that slices the plain into `s` section.

What is the upper limit for `s` as a function of `n` and `e` and `e/n`?

I'm trying to find how little memory I can count on some code using.

---

It's easy to show that `e` is not more than `n*(n-1)/2` but I have a feeling that it's going to be a small integer. For a `n ~= 10` case I have with fixed node position, that overestimates the limit by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 3):

you should look here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic
might help

Comment: hmm. after not thinking about it for a while I noticed that I can get from that to "lim(e/n, n -> inf) = 1 + s/n" but I can't get rid of the s/n.

Answer (score 1):

It can be proven by induction that e <= 3*n - 6. So e/n < 3 and so s/n < 2.